# Not showing div (pop-up) again in 1 day

Tags: cookies

I want the div (pop-up) not to show when it is closed (display: none).

This is my pop up code

```
<!-- popup download -->
<div id="popupDownload" class="popup-download only-mobile">
<div class="popup-download__container"><button type="button" class="popup-download__close" onclick="hidePopupDownload()"> <svg viewbox="0 0 16 16" width="1em" height="1em" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="x" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor" class="bi-x b-icon bi" style="color: grey;"> <g transform="translate(8 8) scale(1.1428 1.1428) translate(-8 -8)"> <path d="M4.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 7.293l2.646-2.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708L8.707 8l2.647 2.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8 8.707l-2.646 2.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L7.293 8 4.646 5.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z"></path> </g> </svg> </button>
<div class="popup-download__image"><img src="https://URL-IMAGE.jpeg" class="flyer-logo" /></div>
<div class="popup-download__text">
<div class="text__title">Title TEXT</div>
<div class="text__sub-title">Sub Title Text</div>
</div>
<div class="popup-download__button-wapper">
<div class="popup-download__button"><a href="https://URL-DOWNLOAD" target="_blank" style="color: white;">Open</a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- popup download -->
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
        function hidePopupDownload(){
            document.getElementById('popupDownload').style.display='none';
        }
// ]]></script>
```

Thank you.

I want to show again the next day.

Comment: Do you use CSS something like "display:flex" in your class ?

Comment: Yes please. I have display:flex for this pop up.

Comment: Maybe you can try this.
document.getElementById('popupDownload').style.setProperty("display","none","important")

Comment: This is my code https://jsfiddle.net/3amr6scf/

Comment: I have tried to put it in but when I refresh it the pop-up is still showing. T.T

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and show us what you have tried first [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You can't expect as to implement all of your cookie logic.